# Tensorflow png as x and html as y

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Using a few examples from around the web, I've come up with this solution and it's so far untested. There's more code for the tensorflow

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from lxml import html
import requests
import imgkit

tree = [0]*255
trees = [0]*255
for x in xrange(255):
    page = requests.get(html)
    tree[x] = html.fromstring(page.content)

    imgkit.from_url(html, 'out.png')
    trees[x] = tf.io.decode_png(
        'out.png',
        channels=0,
        dtype=tf.dtypes.uint8,
        name=None
    )
# mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
# (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = (trees[0:200], tree[0:200]), (trees[200:255], tree[200:255])
```

The rest of the code is found here:
https://github.com/YunYang1994/TensorFlow2.0-Examples/blob/master/2-Basical_Models/CNN.py

Is this something that should work to create HTML from a given screenshot of a lookalike solution?

It turns out you'll need to import JS and CSS to get even close to a proper solution and then all you'll be approximating as error for will be the backend which if you've coded for that can be quite complex. Ideally you'd use only sites that have been flagged as safe for "tor" users; javascript disabled.